# Как получить ID беседы с помощью VK API?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Мне нужно получать ID беседы вк, чтобы писать в нее с нескольких страниц. Беда в том, что на каждом для каждой личной страницы ID беседы разный. Существует ли метод vk api, позволяющий определить ID беседы по ее названию или как-либо иначе?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел нужный метод, но он будет работать только если беседа с таким названием единственная или только в ней существует активность. Это метод messages.searchConversations().
В Python это выглядит как-то так:

```
import vk_api
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='токен')
vk = vk_session.get_api()
chat_id = vk.messages.searchConversations(q='название беседы', count=1)['items'][0]['peer']['local_id']
```

Подробнее о нем можно почитать в официальной документации: https://vk.com/dev/messages.searchConversations